# Replication Working in AD

Tags: active-directory, replication

I recently studied the concept of replication in Active directory. My doubt is, which one initiates the replication?

For example, I had DC-1 and DC-2 server. I update the user object's name attribute from **"Sam"** to **"John"** in DC-1 server. I studied in some sites, they told that the DC-2 identify the update of object in DC-1 and then request to get the update from DC-1 server. If this is the actual working flow, my question is, how the DC-2 identify the update in DC-1. If this is not, DC-1 server send notification to DC-2 server that the update happened in DC-1 server?

If anybody knows the working flow, kindly post your answer.

Thanks,
Sathishkumar T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domain controllers pull changes from partner DC's by requesting the highest USN, and replicates changes for the USN it previously had for that DC and the current highest USN. Within a site, the originating DC notifies its replication partners of the changes when they occur. Between sites the replication is performed on a schedule, unless the site link has been configured to use change notifications.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4592.how-active-directory-replication-works.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Greg Askew